# Queries on user_cons_columns much slower in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We're in the process of upgrading from Oracle 11g to 12c, and have noticed that queries on user_cons_columns seem to be quite a bit slower.

For example this is about 4 times as slow, even on a smaller dataset:

```
select uc.search_condition 
from user_constraints uc inner join user_cons_columns ucc on ucc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = uc.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
where ucc.table_name = :upper_table_name
and ucc.column_name = :upper_column
```

Could it just be a matter of gathering statistics?

Comment: But where are you checking those values? Have you upgraded already? you might encounter some performance degradation after an in-place upgrade. Ps: you only have that query that you noticed to be slow? All the others queries to other tables are the same?

Comment: This is on a clean test 12c system that we have done a clean install of our application on, so not an upgrade. No other queries seem to have this problem.

Comment: I'm sure there was a strong recommendation by Oracle to NOT gather stats on the data dictionary tables, so I would check before doing this. Best place to start with your issue is explain plan and compare to the previous version.

Comment: @TenG - that may have been true a long time ago but since 11G (if not earlier) Oracle have recommended that we can stats on the data dictionary. That's why DBMS_STATS has a [GATHER_DICTIONARY_STATS() procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_stats.htm#i1055451)

Answer (score 5):

In my experience selects from `user_constraints` and `user_cons_columns` and other data dictionary views have been slow for several major Oracle versions. Not just 12c. Doing `dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;` speeded up the first query below between 10-20%.

But what was *really* helpful was to rewrite the query to select from  `with` clause "tables" using the `/*+materialized*/` hint instead of selecting directly from the `user_` tables.

This query is very slow on my setup, about **150 seconds**: (it returns all foreign keys on a list of tables, including table and column names in both ends of the foreign keys)

```
select
  cc.table_name, cc.position, cc.constraint_name, cc.column_name,
  cr.table_name r_table_name, ccr.constraint_name r_constraint_name, ccr.column_name r_column_name
from user_constraints   c
join user_cons_columns  cc on cc.constraint_name=c.constraint_name and
                              cc.owner=c.owner and 
                              cc.table_name=c.table_name
join user_constraints   cr on cr.owner=c.r_owner and
                              cr.constraint_name=c.r_constraint_name and
                              cr.constraint_type in ('P','U')
join user_cons_columns ccr on ccr.constraint_name=cr.constraint_name and
                              ccr.owner=cr.owner and
                              ccr.table_name=cr.table_name and
                              ccr.position=cc.position
where c.constraint_type='R'
and c.table_name in ('TABLE_A', 'TABLE_B', ........a list of about 157 table names.......)
order by cc.table_name, cc.position, constraint_name, column_name, cc.position;
```

After rewriting to this, the query use just **1-8 seconds**:

```
with
uc  as (select /*+materialize*/ owner,table_name,constraint_name,constraint_type,r_owner,r_constraint_name  from user_constraints),
ucc as (select /*+materialize*/ owner,table_name,constraint_name,position,column_name from user_cons_columns)
select
  cc.table_name, cc.position, cc.constraint_name, cc.column_name,
  cr.table_name r_table_name, ccr.constraint_name r_constraint_name, ccr.column_name r_column_name
from uc     c
join ucc   cc on cc.constraint_name=c.constraint_name and cc.owner=c.owner and cc.table_name=c.table_name
join uc    cr on cr.owner=c.r_owner and cr.constraint_name=c.r_constraint_name and cr.constraint_type in ('P','U')
join ucc  ccr on ccr.constraint_name=cr.constraint_name and ccr.owner=cr.owner and ccr.table_name=cr.table_name and ccr.position=cc.position
where c.constraint_type='R'
and c.table_name in ('TABLE_A', 'TABLE_B', ........a list of about 157 table names.......)
order by cc.table_name, cc.position, constraint_name, column_name, cc.position;
```

I also tried `*` instead of listing just the needed columns in the `with` tables, but that didn't help. I'm guessing it's because Oracle ignore `/*+materialize*/` hints if too much data is to be remembered/cached.

Comment: Thanks - super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

**1. Gather dictionary stats.**

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;
end;
/
```

**2. Gather fixed object stats.**

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats;
end;
/
```

There are also a few rare data dictionary objects that are never analyzed unless you specifically call them with `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats`.

**3. Look for broken data dictionary objects.**  In [some rare cases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118478/recreate-fixed-views) character set problems can cause data dictionary performance problems.  Run an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on the `SELECT` and look for anything "weird", like `NLSSORT` in the predicates that would prevent an index access.

**4. Check My Oracle Support.**  I've seen bugs before for data dictionary views that degrade with new versions.  Sometimes there's an alternate version of the data dictionary view that fixes the problem.  I searched on My Oracle Support and "Data Dictionary Select Taking A Very Long Time in 12c (Doc ID 2251730.1)" may be relevant here.  I can't post the contents of that article here so go to support.oracle.com and check out the workaround in that bug report.

**5. Consider yourself lucky.** If you only have one performance problem, and it's only four times slower, I'd consider that a successful upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I've gathered the stats you suggested, but don't yet see an improvement. I'll try your other suggestions too. I note that I'm not the only person to report this https://community.oracle.com/thread/3703081

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to this party but as suggested by [Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tuning_oracle_dictionary_sql.htm), use the /*+ RULE */ hint with your queries on the Oracle data dictionary. This effectively turns off the optimizer.

[Many](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizer-hints/) have said not to use hints and that the RULE hint has been [deprecated](https://logicalread.com/oracle-11g-optimizer-changes-affect-tuning-mc02/) but it makes a huge difference in my case. One of my DBA_IND_COLUMNS queries which took 18 ***MINUTES*** to run now takes less than a second (Oracle 12cR1). At a loss to say why this works...

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Yup, /*+RULE*/ also helped.